# New NLog package always creates NLog.config files

Tags: c#, nlog

I have updated the NLog library throughout our solution to 4.4.1.

With the old version 4.3.11, we used the `MyApp.exe.nlog` configuration file, which is correctly configured and available.

The new library version has created new `NLog.config` files and scattered them through our projects, and logging stopped working.

I have deleted them and NLog seemed to find our config files and logging started working again. However, when I compile a certain console application project, a new NLog.config is created in the output directory, so in that application logging does not work.

How can I force NLog to work with what it finds, and not to create new `NLog.config` files at will?

Comment: Did you install NLog.config package?

Comment: I did not install any new package, but I may have updated an existing copy. I cannot access the repo from home, will have to look into that tomorrow. Would that change anything?

Comment: NLog.config creates a nlog.config on install. Maybe just the NLog package is better for this case.